# Login plugin messing with HTML DOM structure

Tags: html, css, facebook, plugins, authentication

I've integrated the facebook login in a site which seems to be the source of some trouble.

Whenever I log in with the 'regular way' (by an self created field) there is no problem, but once I use a facebook login the divs of the site are getting messed up.

I've got a wrapper with a width of 90% of the page, inside this div there are two divs one named content with 80% of the width of the wrapper and the other once receives the other 20% of the width.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        content here...
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        side bar items etc.
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to check the source / inspect elements of the site it shows up perfectly
with the regular login. However once I login with facebook the following pops up:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        content here...
        <div id="sidebar">
            side bar items etc.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this caused by the facebook plugin loading, whilst php/html is not waiting to generate any content and just continues? I am 100% sure this is caused by the login as I excluded any other option.

Comment: By "self created field" you mean the filed generated by Facebook or written by you..? Also F12 gives you the static source right..? You need to check for the dynamic HTML.. Use Firebug addon in Firefox

Comment: I used firebug to discover this, and yes the field is self created.
If i check the source (ctrl + u for windows) everything seems ok, but the dynamic generated content (what F12 shows) is off.

Comment: could you share the Facebook login code here.. I guess you need to specify where Facebook needs to place its login code

Comment: what do you mean exactly? the api key? The user logs in on a different page, the only thing that exists on the page i'm talking about is a session with cookies of facebook that i'm logged in.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Its been a while since I used Facebook Login plugin :). See Facebook APIs should not interfere with your DOM.. In fact it gives the developer complete control where the facebook login button is to be placed. So I would suggest re-naming the IDs of DIVs as it seems some other plugin has re-strucutered the DOM and placed `#sidebar` inside `#wrapper > #content`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add an element which would hold/wrap arround the Facebook login with fixed dimensions(width/height) and the css property `overflow:hidden`